# Blender 2.8 - No theme presets?

Tags: theme

I'm really sorry if it's something dumb I'm doing, but for whatever reason, I have no other presets to select from than those in the pic below, and I swear there were others when I was checking 2.8 when the beta first released

[image: blender->preferences->themes]

Has something changed since then? Or did I perhaps delete a file by mistake? or is there an option I need to check or something?
I know there's something wrong here because I just checked a YouTube video and this guy had a bunch of presets (just as I remember)

[image: YouTube video snip]

I've googled but couldn't find anything (besides user shared themes) Again, I'm terribly sorry if it's something dumb from my part! It's been a couple of months since I gave 2.8 a visit.

Comment: I wonder if you don't need to download and install now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Developers have decided that there were too many themes shipped by default with Blender.

Some were of poor quality, unfinished or not well supported; maintaining them and updating for the new UI is also a lot of work. Developer time is better spent on other features and refining these two to a higher polish level.

Rather than shipping a multitude of themes of dubious quality it is better to focus on two well supported high quality themes instead. One dark and one light, should suffice to please most users taste.

You can still make your own if you like or [download and install third party ones](https://blenderartists.org/c/coding/released-scripts-and-themes). A [call for content](https://developer.blender.org/rBSde231887b44fd867a5ee2de1a6a0c58635d71abf) has been put up if users want to contribute their own.

Comment: Oh, I see. Big thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Don't post "Thank you" comments. If an answer helped you upvote it, and if it solved you problem consider marking it as accepted.